# How does a person fix 'element not interactable' Selenium and C# when it isn't clear what element is in use?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to automate through a set of dropdown fields that would filter down a database of tickets and export a csv for further processing.  One of the fields is an "Owner" dialog box where a person can type in a name, a drop down tries to figure out the full name from a backend database.  I only am filtering with one person's name.  Through the course of trial and error: I am getting the following exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable
>     (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)'

Using the Selenium IDE to step through the website and record each step, an export produces the following (in Java):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".col-xs-2:nth-child(7) .ui-select-search")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ng-touched")).sendKeys("First Lastname");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ng-touched")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

So I utilized those elements in my code, (even though I am unable to locate them in the HTML code block):

```
var owner = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".col-xs-2:nth-child(7)"));
owner.Click();
```

This successfully clicks on the field, I need to fill in a name in the field.

```
owner.SendKeys("First Last");
```

This produces the error. I've tried various By.CssSelectors, By.Id, By.XPath including By.XPath("*[@placeholder='Owner']") and waiting various time (X) using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(X);`

In further researching, I tried the following code:

```
elements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("employee-search"));
foreach (IWebElement a in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
}
```

This yields:

```
Element (id = 54e057b8-2ca1-4d35-a73e-1cbdc068b50b)
Element (id = 4d0aae2b-fc01-4658-8585-54b415cb1c33)
Element (id = 1a94ce3f-ec5e-4c6b-aab2-4df26159d686)
```

If I edit the .ToString() to .Text, as in the following:

```
elements = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("employee-search"));
foreach (IWebElement a in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.Text);
}
```

The console doesn't produce any output.

This is the HTML block I am working from:

```
<div class="ui-select-container selectize-control single ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched open" ng-class="{'open': $select.open}" ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled" ng-model="$ctrl.employee.selected" theme="selectize" append-to-body="true" on-select="$ctrl.selectEmployee($item, $model)" skip-focusser="true" style="position: absolute; left: 1226.5px; top: 281px; width: 207.104px;">
    <div class="selectize-input focus" ng-class="{'focus': $select.open, 'disabled': $select.disabled, 'selectize-focus' : $select.focus}" ng-click="$select.open &amp;&amp; !$select.searchEnabled ? $select.toggle($event) : $select.activate()" style="">
        <div ng-hide="$select.searchEnabled &amp;&amp; ($select.open || $select.isEmpty())" class="ui-select-match ng-hide" placeholder="Owner">
            <span ng-show="!$select.searchEnabled &amp;&amp; ($select.isEmpty() || $select.open)" class="ui-select-placeholder text-muted ng-hide">Owner</span>
            <span ng-hide="$select.isEmpty() || $select.open" ng-transclude="" class="ng-hide"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="search" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" class="ui-select-search ui-select-toggle ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-empty" ng-class="{'ui-select-search-hidden':!$select.searchEnabled}" ng-click="$select.toggle($event)" placeholder="Owner" ng-model="$select.search" ng-hide="!$select.isEmpty() &amp;&amp; !$select.open" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" aria-label="Select box" style="width: 194px;">
    </div>
```

I'm expecting that a SendKeys statement to input a First and Last Name, followed by a return to add that to the filter parameters prior to exporting a CSV. Interacting with the website allows for a click in the field, keyboard input and if a positive match is made, press enter to lock in the filter. Instead, depending on the element I am looking up, it will tell me it isn't interactable or not located.  My suspicion is it requires JavascriptExecutor. What would that look like as I assume I would need to flip tags like:

```
ng-show="!$select.searchEnabled"
```

To enable them (without !). Please comment to help me if any of this is confusing, improperly formatted, further information is needed, etc. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be great if in the future, you take a minute to reread your post after submitting it to make sure that it's formatted properly.

Comment: There are no elements in the posted HTML that match your posted CSS selector, `.col-xs-2:nth-child(7)` or a tagname of `employee-search` and your XPath isn't even valid. You need to take some time and look over the current code you are using, post a [mcve], update the relevant HTML, make sure that the error message is current, and look the rest of your question over to make sure it's relevant also. All we have to work from is what you post... make sure it's accurate.

Comment: Printing `a.ToString()`, as you saw, prints Selenium's internal ID of the element. I'm assuming you meant to print `a.Text`?

Comment: I'm a long time lurker, this is my first time posting.  I usually am able to glean wisdom from existing posts, but I ran into this wall and need to reach out for further assistance.  I appreciate the feedback and I will continue to edit and clarify the post.  Digging through the HTML for relevant code is the problem as I am not developing site, and therefor do not know what is entailed to access the backend of the JavaScript.  But I will gather more and see if I can create something reproducible.